# What are the most useful bookmarklets for a superuser who do not have extension support?

Tags: bookmarklet

After the release of Google Chrome I changed my default browser from Firefox to Chrome. I was a fan of Firefox but Chrome was what I've been waiting for because of its speed and some other features. I was using a lot of extensions in Firefox, but now as I am using [beta channel](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/) releases I don't have extension (plugin) support yet. So I entered the world of [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). I know they are not as efficient as extensions but they serve some of my intentions.

Here is the question: I wonder if I am missing some very useful bookmarklets. What are the most useful bookmarklets for a superuser who do not have extension support?

Comment: You mention that you may be missing some very useful bookmarklets, which I'm implies that you have some already. Can you share which ones you use that you like so we can get an idea of what you might be looking for?

Comment: once I wrote my choice to a question like this, people warned me to write it as an answer. so I wrote it as an answer down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two links to some useful bookmarklets:

[Guide to Most Useful Bookmarklets for Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.](http://www.labnol.org/internet/guide-to-useful-bookmarklets/7931/)

[25 brilliant bookmarklets to boost your browsing](http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/25-best-bookmarklets-to-boost-your-browsing-613473)

Comment: You may be able to add a second link to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am using those:

- Google Reader Subscribe (I think chrome still does not recognize rss feeds, does it?)
- GMail This
- Delicious
- TinyURL
- [Instapapers](http://www.instapaper.com/) Read Later
- [Remove Css](http://dorward.me.uk/software/disablecss/) (instead of one functionality of Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox)
- [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/)

Comment: I would recommend waiting a day or two before answering your own question, if you actually want someone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like bookmarklets because they work across many browsers. I suppose it depends on which services/sites you like but my favorite are:

- Google Reader, **Subscribe** button and **Note in Reader** button
- Google Bookmarks, **Google Bookmark this** button so I can keep a centralized bookmark collection across all machines and browers... I rarely use browser bookmarks
- a button (bookmarklet) called View Cookies with the code:

  ```
  javascript:alert(document.cookie)
  ```

  to view cookes from that domain.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Shortwave](http://shortwaveapp.com/), which pops up a simple dialog box into which you can type search queries. The useful part is that you can direct them to Wikipedia, Google Image Search, Youtube, etc, with the letter you put at the beginning of a command.

For me it's like Quicksilver / Launchy / etc in my browser. If you can host a simple text file then it's possible to customize commands, too.

Comment: Thanks for the Shortwave pointer.  For those who can't or don't want to host a text file, http://shortmarks.com provides a similar service that lets you customize your commands.  (Full disclosure: I created Shortmarks)